# How can I determine the wall clock time of a process?

Tags: time

I have found the general Linux program `time`, which times a command.  For example, suppose I want to time the execution of `foo`.  I can use:

```
time foo
```

which gives this sample output:

```
real    0m8.738s
user    0m5.796s
sys     0m0.576s
```

However, the man page for `time` seems a bit unclear (although I am a Linux novice):

> ```
> TIME(1)                       Linux User's Manual                      TIME(1)
>
>
>
> NAME
>        time - time a simple command or give resource usage
>
> SYNOPSIS
>        time [options] command [arguments...]
>
> DESCRIPTION
>        The  time  command  runs  the  specified program command with the given
>        arguments.  When command finishes, time writes a  message  to  standard
>        error  giving  timing statistics about this program run.  These statis-
>        tics consist of (i) the elapsed real time between invocation and termi-
>        nation, (ii) the user CPU time (the sum of the tms_utime and tms_cutime
>        values in a struct tms as returned by times(2)), and (iii)  the  system
>        CPU  time  (the  sum of the tms_stime and tms_cstime values in a struct
>        tms as returned by times(2)).
> ```

Does the "real" time refer to the ***wall clock*** time?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Real" time is elapsed time, which is usually the difference between wall clock times, but not always.

For example, if you start a process at 01:59:00 on the day in which daylight-savings (summer) time takes effect in a locale in which the time change is at 02:00, and the process takes two minutes, then the real elapsed time will be two minutes, while the wall clock will show a difference of one hour and two minutes. (When the time offset changes back, the wall clock difference will be negative, but the real elapsed time will continue to be the same.)

Comment: So to extend the metaphor, the "real" time is "**stop watch**" time.

Comment: See also: [Why real time can be lower than user time](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/40694/4784)