# how to know the use of my applications?

Tags: ubuntu, monitoring, process-management

I want to know how long my programs have been used. For example if I use my web browser I want to know the start and the close time to obtain a total of use time.

Basically I want to know when an application starts an when its ends, and in function of the event do something like register the time in a file.

I've searched about listening kernel events or something like that but nothing. Also i tried with `supervisord` but it says that the process closes too quickly and did not record anything.

Another of my attempts was to use the `pyinotify` library to monitor the `/proc` folders but that was a complete failure.

I'm working in Ubuntu. Any tips?

These are my sources

- https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify
- http://supervisord.org/

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79703/how-can-i-determine-the-wall-clock-time-of-a-process

Comment: It sounds like you want a report of all the times you've spent using various processes, correct?

Comment: @sim Exactly that.

Answer (score 3):

You could use BSD process accounting. `lastcomm` doesn't report the elapsed time, but at least on Linux, it's stored in the accounting database and can be queried with the `dump-acct` command.

```
$ sudo accton on # activate process accounting
$ sleep 5.23
$ sudo dump-acct /var/log/account/pacct | grep '^sleep'
sleep       |v3|     0.00|     0.00|   523.00| 10031| 10031| 14632.00|     0.00|   15261      416|Mon Jun  2 17:09:37 2014
```

The elapsed time is the 5th field (above 523 centi-seconds).

The 3rd and 4th fields are the user time and system time, that is the time the CPU (any CPU) spent running that process (any thread of that process).

Note that (at least on Linux), the process is accounted when it (any thread of its) dies and as the process name it had when it died. That means that for instance in:

```
sh -c 'sleep 4; exec sleep 5'
```

One process executes `sh` and then forks another process to execute `sleep 4` and then the first process executes `sleep 5` (therefore changing name). In the accounting database, we get:

```
sleep           |v3|     0.00|     0.00|   400.00|  1000|  1000| 10320.00|     0.00|   28867    28866|Tue Jun  3 07:45:52 2014
sleep           |v3|     0.00|     0.00|   900.00|  1000|  1000| 10320.00|     0.00|   28866    28801|Tue Jun  3 07:45:52 2014
```

That is the process that runs `sh` and then `sleep 5` is accounted as `sleep` for a duration of 900 centi-seconds, and there's no mention of `sh`.

For `firefox` (a heavily multi-threaded application) unfortunately, in my case, I see very short times, because the process is accounted when one short-lived thread of its dies.

Comment: That was what I looking for.
What is the difference between user time, system time and effective time.
Thanks!!!!